# LDAP connection reset timer

Tags: ldap

I am creating LDAP connection using initialldapcontext.
I see there is option like 
jndi.ldap.read.timeout - time to wait for read operation
jndi.ldap.connect.timeout - time to wait for connect operation.

I have a requirement where the ldap connection is active but still I have terminated it based on a timer.
For exmaple: there are three ldap server and there is time 5 min. So once a ldap connection is opened it has to be active only for 5 min then it should terminate and then reconnect.
It is some thing like maximum session time for a ldap session.
Whether there is any flag like jndi.ldap.read.timeout or jndi.ldap.connect.timeout for this purpose.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't be holding LDAP connections for even as long as five minutes. You should *logically* close them as soon as you've carried out the operation you're doing. A connection pool will amortize the costs of reconnection.

Comment: The case where I am planning to use is a server where there are lot of request coming and I have only one LDAP server to connected. This is the reason why I hold the connection for long time.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a connection pool. The [JNDI LDAP provider documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/jndi-ldap.html) shows that there is a system property called com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.timeout which would do the disconnect part for you. Not the automatic reconnect, though. However, establishing a new connection should not be very expensive (unless you really need to optimize for speed/scale).

The UnboundID LDAP SDK (disclaimer: I work for UnboundID) has more flexible options. See the [LDAPConnectionPool](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/LDAPConnectionPool.html) class for more details.

Comment: Hi Bertold Kolics, The com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.timeout indicates the maximum time a session can be idle. My case is even if connection is not idle I need to disconnect the session. The timer I need should specify the maximum time a connection can be used from the time when it is connected.

Comment: I would be really surprised if you could accomplish what you are describing with JNDI. Your best bet would be implement managing your own connections. Is there any particular reason why you have to close a connection even if it has not been idle?